# How to determine the number of affine lines in

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, finite-fields, affine-geometry

$(\mathbb{F}_2)^2$ ?

I know that the number of vectorial lines which is $3$ (indeed there are three independent vectorial lines in $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$). I was wondering how to proceed with the affine lines this time (for each point the line could go in three directions).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's the same as the number of pairs of points since a line over $\mathbf F_2$ contains only two points.

Comment: @Bernard So here it will be $3$ ?

Comment: Draw 4 dots and find how many ways you can connect two dots. It should be 6.

Comment: You have $3$ vectorial lines and $3$ affine lines (not passing through the origin).

Comment: @Bernard In general is the number of vectorial lines the same as the number of affine lines in $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ ?

Comment: @정준환 It depends if you want independent lines you have to delete $3$ lines of the $6$...

Comment: @Maman: I should think about it (no time at the moment), but  the case of $\mathbf F_2$ is particular: the field has two elements, and  a line is defined by two points, independently of the characteristic.

Comment: @Maman, I don't know what a vectorial line is (sounds like a made up definition), but in any case, a line passing through the origin is also an affine line. Ax+b, with b=0.

Comment: There are many ways to define lines in higher order fields. The correct notion is often attributed to the one given by those working on the Kakeya conjecture. (Google it)